# Get attributes assigned to property of a Type using an instance of that property

Tags: c#, json.net

I've come to a problem which I need to know if an attribute was placed on a property of a class but I'm limited because realistically all I got is an instance of that property to work with (type is not useful in this scenario).

The problem comes from the fact that I'm working with json.net using a custom  ContractResolver to detect such attributes but all you get from the DefaultContractResolver is a type or an instance in the case you use the ShouldSerialize predicate.

I can't use Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(type) because the attribute is not on the type. Had no luck with TypeDescriptor either. I'm thinking if its possible getting the memberinfo from that instance so I could pass that to GetCustomAttributes, is this even possible? Do you see any other way?

Btw what I want to accomplish is to put a marker attribute on some properties so that my contract resolver can serialize only some properties of that type instead of all of them. I would not want to put this on the type itself as sometimes I want to serialize the whole object. It is also not practical to create a contract resolver for each type because that would be massive.

```
var instance = new MyClass();

instance.MyProperty = new OtherClass();

// propertyValue is all I get when I'm on the ShouldSerializeMethod
object propertyInstance = instance.MyProperty;

var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(propertyInstance.GetType());

// this returns no attributes since the attribute is not on the type but on the property of another type
Console.WriteLine (attributes.Length);

public class MyClass
{
    [MyCustomAttribute]
    public OtherClass MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Bray as mentioned, it's not possible and it makes perfect sense why it doesn't.

However, to accomplish what I was set out to do, I managed to do it but instead of using my own marker attribute and then hoping to use a ContractResolver override, I used json.net attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SerializeOnlyWhatIWantOnThisPropertyConverter))]
```

This way we can rely on json.net's code to keep doing its job while allowing us to on a per property basis, to filter out what we want to serialize. The downside of this is that the implementation of the converter is more verbose and error prone and we can't use other features that the ContractResolver offers like TypeNameHandling. I also believe that the ResolveContract route is more efficient as it has builtin cache, although I still haven't done any benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

You are OH so close...   just get the property from the class (using reflection) and then use [GetCustomAttributes(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes.aspx) from the `PropertyInfo`.  To get all of the attributes applied to the property, use:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
var attList = obj.GetType()
                 .GetProperty("MyProperty")
                 .GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

or if you want just a specific attribute type:'

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
var attList = obj.GetType()
                 .GetProperty("MyProperty")
                 .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
```

Note that there's no such thing as an attribute that is applied to an *instance* of a class - the attributes are always on the class itself.  So trying to get a custom attribute for an instance will be fruitless.

Comment: Thanks Michael, however, when I'm on the ShouldSerialize method, all I get is that propertyValue variable which has no idea where it came from. So all I know is that that propertyValue is of type OtherClass and it doesn't know that it was defined as a property of MyClass (which is where the attrobite is defined). Yes, attributes are assigned to types, properties, fields but in this case all I have is that instance property. I've edited the title to hopefuly be clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the difficulty...  if you have an instance variable `obj`, then just use `obj.GetType().GetProperty...`

Comment: OOhhhh  hmm   there is no way to get from a property value back to the object that references that object, unless it's part of the property that you have.  If *that's* what you need then you are out of luck.

Comment: That's the thing, json.net's JsonProperty.ShouldSerialize predicate method gives you propertyValue, it doesn't tell you that it belongs to MyClass or that even MyClass exists or belongs to the "main" object being serialized. Which is why I was asking if, since I have the propertyValue instance, can I find out the Type that instance belongs to (in this case MyClass). With that, your code would be perfect

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that.  A value type wouldn't even be the same object, and a reference type might have multiple references to it, so there's no way this is going to happen.  Sounds like you need some refactoring, perhaps.